# Linear System $3\times 3$ using algebra only no Gauss

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have a system 3x3 i dont want to use the Gauss method how with using algebra can i solve this equations ? There are 4 variables unknown
$$x+y+lz=1$$
$$x+ly+z=1$$
$$lx+y+z=1$$
I know if there are 3, i try to eliminate 1 but here there is one more.How can i solve this?

Comment: except then(first time hear this)only algebra

Comment: Hint: What happens if you add the three equations together? What values can $l$ take? What are the values of $x,y,z$ in this case?

Comment: 2x+lx+ly+2y+2z+lz=3

Comment: is $l$ assumed to be a variable? or a Parameter?

Comment: Yes. In other words, $(l + 2)(x + y + z) = 3$. What values of $l$ does that rule out? Can you think of at least one solution for all other values of $l$? Can you see that that is the only solution?

Comment: Treat $l$ as a parameter (as if it were fixed); then in the solution to the (now linear) system just allow it to vary. Thus it is enough to think of 3 equations in 3 unknowns.

Comment: can you solve it because i cant understand what you mean to treat it

Comment: My point is that you say "there are 4 unknowns", but you can solve the problem by pretending $l$ is known, solving for $x,y,z$, and then allowing $l$ to change. As for solving it, just use symmetry: each of the equations is mapped into another if you interchange variables, so $x=y=z$ is a solution. The issue is whether there are others, and sometimes there *are* others.

Comment: sorry give me time i try to understand

Comment: @Ian, the fact that the solution for fixed $l$ is unique is not obvious without some linear algebra.

Comment: @MeesdeVries That's not what I said. If I swap $x$ and $z$ then $x+y+lz=1$ becomes $lx+y+z=1$ which is the third equation. Similar for swapping any other pair of variables. The system as a whole is left entirely invariant by interchanges of variables. But you have a point about special values of $l$.

Comment: @Ian, yes, and that is also true of the system $x + y + z = 1$. The fact that the solution for fixed $l$ is unique is crucial and non-trivial without any linear algebraic insight.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Ah yes, I was already implicitly using some linear algebraic *concepts* even if not linear algebraic *manipulation*.

Comment: where can i see similars exercises with 3x3 or 2x2 using and have an l?thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with $$x=1-y-lz$$ we get in the second and third equation
$$1-y-lz+z=1$$ this gives
$$(1-l)(z-y)=0$$
and
$$l(1-y-lz)+y+z=1$$ which simplifyes to
$$y(1-l)+z(1-l^2)=1-l$$
now do case work!

Comment: I try to understand .You use x+y+lz=1 and you solve it to x and it is x=1−y−lz ok until this point.(1-l)(z-y)=0  and y(1−l)+z(1−l2)=1−l .After i know what to do but i dont understand how you get to those.Sorry if you could explain it more

Comment: i have plugged in $$x=1-y-lz$$ in the other two equations

Comment: why should he/she do this?

Comment: i should insert some steps

Comment: you add the second  and the third?x+ly+z=1 (second) and (third) lx+y+z=1

Answer (score 2):

Gaussian elimination *is* algebra, not witchcraft. The row transformation
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & l & 1 \\
1 & l & 1 & 1 \\
l & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right]
\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & l & 1 \\
0 & l-1 & 1-l & 0 \\
l & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
corresponds to subtracting the first equation from the second.

You can see the matrices just as shorthands for the equations with the unknowns. The same operation on the explicit equations would bring the system in the form
\begin{cases}
x+y+lz=1 \\[4px]
(l-1)y+(1-l)z=0 \\[4px]
lx+y+z=1
\end{cases}
and you can see there is no difference whatsoever, except for the *representation*.

The next transformation
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & l & 1 \\
0 & l-1 & 1-l & 0 \\
l & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right]
\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & l & 1 \\
0 & l-1 & 1-l & 0 \\
0 & 1-l & 1-l^2 & 1-l
\end{array}\right]
$$
corresponds to multiply the first equation by $l$ and subtracting from the third equation.

Now, if $l=1$ we can see that the system is just $x+y+z=1$, which has infinitely many solutions.

If $l\ne1$, we can divide the second and third equations by $l-1$, getting
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & l & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & -1-l & -1
\end{array}\right]
$$
and we can add the second equation to the third, getting
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & l & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2-l & -1
\end{array}\right]
\tag{*}
$$
If $l\ne-2$, we can divide the third equation by $-2-l$ and get
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & l & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{l+2}
\end{array}\right]
$$
We can now do the back substitutions: add the third equation to the second and then the third equation multiplied by $-l$ to the first, getting
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 0 & 1-\frac{l}{l+2} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{l+2} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{l+2}
\end{array}\right]
$$
Now subtract the second equation from the first, getting (after easy calculations)
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{l+2} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{l+2} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{l+2}
\end{array}\right]
$$
which can be read as
\begin{cases}
x=\frac{1}{l+2} \\[4px]
y=\frac{1}{l+2} \\[4px]
z=\frac{1}{l+2}
\end{cases}

If $l=-2$ the third equation in (*) reads $0=-1$, so the system has no solution.

---

What's the advantage of Gaussian elimination? That you need no clever trick. Of course in this particular case there's a slick one, which you find in the fine answer by paulinho.

I would *never* consider successive substitutions, if it's possible to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming $l$ is a constant. (But this solution works even if it isn't and one of the other variables is given). Adding the three equations, one obtains $$(l+2)(x+y+z)=3$$ and thus $$x+y+z=\frac{3}{l+2}.$$ Now you can subtract each of the original equations from this expression. So for $x$, it would be $$(1-l)x=\frac{3}{l+2}-1.$$ Simplifying by making the right side into one fraction and eliminating common terms, we see that $x=1/(l+2)$. By symmetry, we have $$x=y=z=\frac{1}{l+2}.$$ If l isn't a constant but some other variable is (say $x$ is), still the expression above holds (except for $l=1,-2$).

Comment: Except when $l=1$.

Comment: @Ian Yes, good point.

Comment: i think the solution above is not right

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner If the system has exactly one solution, then $x=y=z$, because permuting the unknowns doesn't modify the system. Since $\frac{3}{l+2}-1=\frac{1-l}{l+2}$, when $l\ne 1$ and $l\ne -2$ the solution is $x=y=z=\frac{1}{l+2}$. If $l=1$ the system has infinitely many solutions; if $l=-2$ the system has no solution.